# How can I use exported strings as my elements in Puppeteer

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I can't seem to declare a string const and use that as my element with Puppeteer. For example:

```
await page.click("#playerView");
```

Works fine, but:

```
const playerViewId = "#playerView";

await page.click(playerViewId);
```

Doesn't. I ultimately want to hold all my Page Elements in an object in a separate file to tidy up my project.

Any ideas why this isn't working?

Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate why you think it doesn't work? It seems like it should.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that the following case does in fact work:

```
const playerViewId = '#playerView';
await page.click(playerViewId);
```

If this is not working, consider upgrading your version of Node.js and/or Puppeteer.

If you are trying to define your variable in a separate file, you can use:

```
// external-file.js:
module.exports.playerViewId = '#playerView';

// main-file.js:
const external_variables = require('./external-file');
const playerViewId = external_variables.playerViewId;
await page.click(playerViewId);
```

Additionally, you should check to make sure that the element with id `playerView` exists and has loaded completely before attempting to use [`page.click()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageclickselector-options).